# i want to load data from "Order" table, the "Items" table worked. how can i make both work in c#. im using ms access

Tags: c#

this is an ordering system it is our project for the finals.
i want to show the rows inside the "Order" table. but it doesn't work. but it worked the "Items" table, maybe because it was the first table i made?
please help.

```
if (choice == 1)
        {
            OpenCon();
            Console.WriteLine("ITEM NUMBER      ITEM                STOCK");
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------");

            DataTable dt = LoadData("SELECT * FROM Items");
            for (int r = 0; r < dt.Rows.Count; r++)
            {

                Console.Write(dt.Rows[r]["ItemNumber"].ToString() + "               ");
                Console.Write(dt.Rows[r]["Item"].ToString() + "                ");
                Console.Write(dt.Rows[r]["Stock"].ToString());
                Console.WriteLine();


            }
            CloseCon();
        }

//READ rows
else if (choice == 2)
        {
            OpenCon();
            Console.WriteLine("ITEM NUMBER      ITEM             QUANTITY");
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------");


            DataTable dt2 = LoadData("SELECT * FROM Order");
            for (int i = 0; i <dt2.Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(dt2.Rows[i]["ItemNumber"].ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(dt2.Rows[i]["OrderedItem"].ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(dt2.Rows[i]["Quantity"].ToString());


            }
            CloseCon();

        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Nobody can help you if you don't explain exactly what the problem is

Comment: sorry about that. What I mean is it Does not display the rows inside the table.

Comment: Please decide on the problem where you need help. (1) Load the rows from the database (2) Get the data out of a loaded row (3) Display something (4) other things.